# Make object stick to Robot

Tags: gazebo, collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a robot that has a platform to transport objects. However, if I place a model on top of that platform and move the robot, the object will stay in its place and eventually fall to the floor. Even if I place a Model from the Gazebo library, so I guess there is somethign wrong with the robot.

How do I make my robot sticky?

right now it has these features:

```
<!-- Link0 -->
<gazebo reference="${name}_link">
  <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
  <maxVel>1</maxVel>
  <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
  <dampingFactor>1</dampingFactor>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <kp>1000000</kp>
  <kd>100000</kd>
  <!--<maxContacts>0</maxContacts>-->
</gazebo>
```

the gazebo.urdf.xacro for the robot:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <robot name="robot_base" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

   <gazebo>
     <plugin name="gazebo_ros_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
       <robotNamespace>/robot_base</robotNamespace>
       <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
     </plugin>
   </gazebo>

 </robot>
```

the urdf.xacro for the model:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
  <xacro:include filename="$(find robot_base)/urdf/robot_base.gazebo.xacro" />
  <xacro:include filename="$(find robot_base)/urdf/robot_base.transmission.xacro" />
  <property name="max_force" value="100.0"/>
  <property name="max_torque" value="100.0"/>
  <property name="max_lin_velocity" value="1.0"/>
  <property name="max_rot_velocity" value="1.0"/>
  <property name="min_position" value="-100.0"/>
  <property name="max_position" value="100.0"/>
  <property name="pi" value="3.14159"/>
  <property name="m" value="400"/> <!--mass of object-->
  <property name="h" value="0.645"/> <!--heigth of object-->
  <property name="l" value="1.204"/> <!--length of object-->
  <property name="w" value="0.72"/> <!--width of object-->

  
  <xacro:macro name="robot_base_visual_origin">
    <origin xyz="0.542 0 0.065" rpy="0 0 ${pi}"/>
    <material name="Orange"/>
  </xacro:macro>
  <xacro:macro name="robot_base_collision_origin">
    <origin xyz="0.542 0 0.0651" rpy="0 0 ${pi}"/>
    <material name="Orange"/>
  </xacro:macro>


  
  <xacro:macro name="robot_base_left_arm_mount_origin">
    <origin xyz="0.417 0.175 0.653" rpy="0 0 -1.5707963267948966"/>
    <!--<origin xyz="0.43 0.18 0.645" rpy="0 0 1.5707963267948966"/>-->
  </xacro:macro>
  <xacro:macro name="robot_base_right_arm_mount_origin">
    <origin xyz="0.417 -0.175 0.653" rpy="0 0 -1.5707963267948966"/>
  </xacro:macro>
  <xacro:macro name="robot_base_mast_mount_origin">
    <origin xyz="-0.30 0.230 0.645" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="robot_base" params="parent_link name hardware_interface">
    <joint name="${name}_fixed_base_joint" type="fixed">
       <!--<axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <limit lower="${min_position}" upper="${max_position}" effort="${max_force}" velocity="${max_lin_velocity}"/>-->
       <child link="${name}_virtual_link_0" />
       <parent link="${parent_link}"/>
      </joint>

    <link name="${name}_virtual_link_0">
      <!--<visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
        </geometry>
    
    </collision>-->

      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.001" />
        <inertia
          ixx="0.00000001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="0.00000001" iyz="0.0"
          izz="0.00000001" />
        </inertial>

    
    </link>
    
    <joint name="${name}_joint_x" type="prismatic">
       <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
       <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
       <limit lower="${min_position}" upper="${max_position}" effort="${max_force}" velocity="${max_lin_velocity}"/>
       <parent link="${name}_virtual_link_0"/>
       <child link="${name}_virtual_link_1" />
    </joint>    

    <link name="${name}_virtual_link_1">
      <!--<visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>-->

      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.001" />
        <inertia
          ixx="0.00000001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="0.00000001" iyz="0.0"
          izz="0.00000001" />
        </inertial>

    </link>

    <joint name="${name}_joint_y" type="prismatic">
       <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
       <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
       <limit lower="${min_position}" upper="${max_position}" effort="${max_force}" velocity="${max_lin_velocity}"/>
       <parent link="${name}_virtual_link_1"/>
       <child link="${name}_virtual_link_2" />
    </joint>    

    <link name="${name}_virtual_link_2">
      <!--<visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>-->

      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.001" />
        <inertia
          ixx="0.00000001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="0.00000001" iyz="0.0"
          izz="0.00000001" />
        </inertial>

    </link>

    <joint name="${name}_joint_theta" type="continuous">
       <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
       <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
       <limit effort="${max_torque}" velocity="${max_rot_velocity}" upper="${-1.0 * pi}" lower="${pi}"/>
       <parent link="${name}_virtual_link_2"/>
       <child link="${name}_link" />
    </joint>    

    <link name="${name}_link">

       <visual>
          <xacro:robot_base_visual_origin />
          <geometry>
              <mesh #robot_mesh# />
          </geometry>
      
     
       </visual>

       <collision>
          <xacro:robot_base_collision_origin />
          <geometry>
              <mesh #robot_mesh# />
          </geometry>
      
      <!--<contact_coefficients kd="100" kp="60000"/>-->
       </collision>

      <inertial>
        <mass value="${m}" />
        <inertia
          ixx="${(m * ( l * l + h * h))/12}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="${(m * ( l * l + w * w))/12}" iyz="0.0"
          izz="${(m * ( h * h + h * h))/12}" />
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="${name}_left_arm_mount_joint" type="fixed">
       <xacro:robot_base_left_arm_mount_origin />
       <parent link="${name}_link"/>
       <child link="${name}_left_arm_mount_link" />
    </joint>

    <link name="${name}_left_arm_mount_link">
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.001" />
        <inertia
          ixx="0.00000001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="0.00000001" iyz="0.0"
          izz="0.00000001" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="${name}_right_arm_mount_joint" type="fixed">
       <xacro:robot_base_right_arm_mount_origin />
       <parent link="${name}_link"/>
       <child link="${name}_right_arm_mount_link" />
    </joint>

    <link name="${name}_right_arm_mount_link">
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.001" />
        <inertia
          ixx="0.00000001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="0.00000001" iyz="0.0"
          izz="0.00000001" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="${name}_mast_mount_joint" type="fixed">
       <xacro:robot_base_mast_mount_origin />
       <parent link="${name}_link"/>
       <child link="${name}_link_mast_mount" />
    </joint>

    <link name="${name}_link_mast_mount">
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.001" />
        <inertia
          ixx="0.00000001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="0.00000001" iyz="0.0"
          izz="0.00000001" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!--Extensions -->
    <xacro:robot_base_gazebo name="${name}" />
    <xacro:robot_base_transmission name="${name}" hardware_interface="${hardware_interface}"/>

  </xacro:macro>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14648/make-object-stick-to-robot/) by [Lyndwyrm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2869/lyndwyrm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-10-25**:
How are you moving your robot? Did you turn on contact visualization and check that the models are indeed touching?

**Comment by [Lyndwyrm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2869/lyndwyrm/) on 2016-10-26**:
I am using postion_controllers/JointTrajectoryController, there are several contacts between the object and the robot. I tried setting the mu coefficients of the object and the robot to Inf, but that didn't change anything.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-10-26**:
What version of gazebo are you using? And, can you post your entire model?

**Comment by [Lyndwyrm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2869/lyndwyrm/) on 2016-10-26**:
currently using 2.2.3, i hope the model is understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Created a plugin using Jennifer Buehlers Grasp Plugin as a template.

---

Originally posted by [Lyndwyrm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2869/lyndwyrm/) with karma: 11 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1